# Octave flip function undefined

Tags: octave

Octave [`flip`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/flip.html) is undefined despite being defined in the documentation.  Has it been renamed to something else?

```
>> flip
error: 'flip' undefined near line 1 column 1
>> version
ans = 3.8.0
```

Comment: I would guess that it was introduced in a later version (the current version is 4.2.0). Maybe use `fliplr`, `flipdim` or `flipud` as needed.

Comment: Yeah I guess.  I can't use flipud unfortunately as it's a 3d matrix I'm working on, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So you're just trying to flip the third dimension?

Comment: Flip on dimension 1.  It's an image which is upside down.  This seems to do it:  `rotdim(permute(A, [2 1 3]), 1, [1 2])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flip` was [introduced in 4.0.0](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-4.0.html) ([rev](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/995df67fc912)). In older versions, `flipdim` provides the same functionality. There is [talk](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Matlab-has-implemented-flip-after-only-10-years-deprecate-flipdim-td4666640.html) of deprecating `flipdim` in newer version of Octave.

Also it's worth noting that starting in 4.0.0, `fliplr` and `flipud` also function on N-dimensional matrices.